# Test if something is "False Like"

Tags: powershell

In Python I can say

```py
test_variable = ""
if test_variable:
    print("I wont make it here because I'm False like")

test_variable = False
if test_variable:
    print("I wont make it here because I'm False like")

test_variable = None
if test_variable:
    print("I wont make it here because I'm False like")
```

And in general I can just get away with stating `if variable` to test if something is "False Like."

In PowerShell I've run into the case where I have to check both for `$Null` and empty string.

```
If (($git_pull_output -eq $Null) -or ($git_pull_output -eq ""))
```

Is there a PowerShell is there a way to check if something is "False like"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another simple "false like" test is to just evaluate the variable as a boolean

```
PS C:\Users\Matt> $test = ""
PS C:\Users\Matt> If($test){"'' Test is good"}

PS C:\Users\Matt> $test = $false
PS C:\Users\Matt> If($test){"False test is good"}

PS C:\Users\Matt> $test = " "
PS C:\Users\Matt> If($test){"Space test is good"}

Space test is good
```

Note the only test that succeeded was the when `$test = " "`

If whitespace was an issue you were looking to avoid as well then `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` is the method for you

```
PS C:\Users\Matt> [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace(" ")
True
```

Comment: So in other words, an empty string in PowerShell evaluates to False (contrary to what was stated in the question), and a string containing whitespace evaluates to True. This is exactly the same as Python.

Comment: @dan-gph Empty strings, empty arrays, 0, 0.0,, `$null`, etc. PowerShell indeed behaves like Python in this respect.

Answer (score 3):

`$false` is an automatic variable with the value of false.  See `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`.

However:

> In Powershell I've run into the case where I have to check both for `$Null` and empty string.

For this you should use the [`IsNullOrEmpty()` static member function of the `System.String` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490acw3e(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($git_pull_output)) { [...] }
```

You may also consider the `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` static method.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `IsNullOrEmpty` over using `Matt`'s answer?

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins I think they are functionally the same. The string method is more descriptive and meaningful in code.

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins `IsNullOrEmpty()` behaves slightly different from the way Python evaluates variables. For example, `$v = 0; if ($v) {...}` will work as in Python, but `$v = 0; if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($v)) {...}` won't, because zero is neither null nor empty. If you wan't to replicate Python behavior I would go with Matt's answer. If you don't want numeric zero values to evaluate to `$false` I'd stick with this one.